# Qual ou quais das frases abaixo está(ão) errada(s)?

Tags: infinitivo-pessoal

1. Os países necessitam de ajuda alheia por causa das dívidas externas.
2. Os países solicitam ajuda alheia por causa das dívidas externas.
3. As dívidas externas obrigam os países a solicitarem ajuda alheia.
4. As dívidas externas dos países obrigam-nos a solicitarem ajuda
   alheia.
5. As dívidas externas dos países os obrigam a solicitarem ajuda alheia.

Comment: A dívida externa obriga a solicitar ajuda (mais dívidas) alheia (externa) eu acho que qq opção está errada =)

Comment: Obrigado. Infelizmente um "analfa" como eu ainda tem muito que aprender e um longo caminho a percorrer. Qq 1 çabe diço.

Answer (score 1):

3,4,5. Quando usar o "a" (que será sempre uma preposição na frente do verbo),o verbo deve ficar no infinitivo.

3. As dívidas externas obrigam os países a **solicitar** ajuda alheia.
4. As dívidas externas dos países obrigam-nos a **solicitar** ajuda alheia.
5. As dívidas externas dos países os obrigam a **solicitar** ajuda alheia.